# Getting class of an individual, using SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, rdflib

I want to get the class which an individual belongs to. In more detail, I want to pass a parameter to a method which is an individual using python (using rdflib), method should return class of an individual which it belongs to.

For example: I have a AlcoholicBeverage class, it has subclass Beer and Beer class has a subclass Brands. In Brands class there are many individuals which represents beer brands.
I want to pass a parameter to a method, run SPARQL query to find, xyz is an individual of Brands class.

Ideally I also want to get, xyz is a Beer (because Brands class is subclass of Beer) and Beer is a AlcoholicBeverage.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
SELECT ?class WHERE { xyz a ?class . }
```

Note that `a` is a shorthand for `rdf:type` - see the [SPARQL specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) section 4.2.4

You will only get the superclasses (AlcoholicBeverage, Beer) from this query if they have either been explicitly added to your RDF model, or if you have [inference enabled](https://web.archive.org/web/20131102081900/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/1363/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-rdfsowl-reasoning-for-rdflib) (and the schema loaded into the model), so that they are added implicitly.

Your schema is a bit strange - Beer is clearly a subclass of AlcoholicBeverage, but what is Brands? Why not either make each brand a subclass of Beer (implying that the individuals are actual physical drinks: "This drink is an [Old Peculier](http://www.theakstons.co.uk/Ales/Old-Peculier/), which is a type of Beer"), or make each brand an individual of Beer: "[Old Peculier](http://www.theakstons.co.uk/Ales/Old-Peculier/) is a Beer", for example.  Brands seems to be a sort of informal placeholder that doesn't make sense in a formal schema? Why is Brands plural when your other class names are singular?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion. I believe my problem is, I can not refer to the xyz in correct way. Without filter section, following query works fine, but with the FILTER part, it returns nothing. How can I refer to a class or individual in .owl file?      PREFIX owl: [link] (http://goo.gl/ZwwgT)
        SELECT ?class WHERE { ?sub rdfs:subClassOf ?class .
        FILTER(?sub=owl:Brands)}